# CSS3 Background with Gradient Overlay - Gradient only working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, webkit

I'm trying to overlay a CSS gradient on a background image. I've got it working in Firefox, but in safari and chrome I only get the background image, without a gradient.

(I generated the gradient code using http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, then simply added url() at the end of each line)

**Update:** seems my problem might be that webkit displays the gradient behind the image, not on top like I need, and firefox does.

```
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(99, 130, 169, 0.7) 100%), url(app/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(99, 130, 169, 0.7))), url(app/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.16) 100%), url(app/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,rgba(99, 130, 169, 0.7) 100%), url(app/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,rgba(99, 130, 169, 0.7) 100%), url(app/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,rgba(99, 130, 169, 0.7) 100%), url(app/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; /* W3C */
```

Comment: What requirements do you have that prevent you from just using images?

Comment: fair question, and might be what I do in the end, but I'm trying to have just one grayscale, full-screen background image that I can then totally change the color and look of using different coloured gradient overlays...it's a nice effect in firefox...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using shorthand notation in this case, it will make it much easier to read and maintain (and it fixes the issue). Here is a working example (and a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/yyy7V/):

```
.foo {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(99, 130, 169, 0.7))), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/'); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(99,130,169,.7)), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/'); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(99,130,169,.7)), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/'); /* FF3.6+ */
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(99,130,169,.7)), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/'); /* IE10+ */
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(99,130,169,.7)), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/'); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(99,130,169,0.7)), url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/'); /* W3C */

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - from where i'm sitting, this doesn't work in safari and chrome! The image is on top of the gradient, not behind it. Does work in firefox still. Do you not get the same?

Answer (score 1):

The image *is behind* the gradient in WebKit. It's just that the WebKit code uses another colour, `rgba(0,0,0,0.16)`, which *is a lot more difficult to spot* than the one used for the other browsers, `rgba(99,130,169,0.7)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here comes from the ordering of your CSS.  [Try Chris Coyier's appraoch instead.](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)

```
.gradient-bg {
   background-color: #1a82f7; 
   background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png); 
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#2F2727), to(#1a82f7));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7); 
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
}
```

Comment: thanks - this seems to only show the gradient, not the background image behind it too...